Log or app to find out who/what is changing my input method
Some time ago, something kept changing my keyboard to Greek, and later, it was frequently changing to Chinese.  A software update fixed it.  Another time, it started again, with Korean, and then went away again.
But now, without a software change, it is happening again.  It is set to Chinese every time I open the laptop, but it also changes occasionally when I switch window focus.  What diagnostic tool can tell me why?

See: https://superuser.com/questions/99172/how-to-stop-os-x-from-switching-input-method-keyboard-layout-automatically

An answer there says it is because it is unavailable to the lock screen uiser (root).  But I close and open the laptop several times a day, and it only started doing this today after being OK for months.  At one time, I had my custom method in /Library, but OS updates kept removing it and disabling SIP to put it back was a pain.  There was a non-SIOP place that documentation said it could be put in, but when I put it there, it wasn't selectable.

In System Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources, are the other sources listed? If so, please remove them temporarily, or permanently if you don't need them. Any change? Also, you should not need to disable SIP in order to put something in /Library/Keyboard Layouts. You just need admin privilieges.

You should have no trouble selecting a layout which is in Home/Library/Keyboard Layouts.  Perhaps something amiss with the .keylayout or .bundle if you do

“There was a non-SIOP place that documentation said it could be put in…” What documentation? What place?

@LincD.   I think both Library and Home/Library are non-SIOP.  Only System/Library should be a problem.

/System/Library/Keyboard Layouts is on the SSV and can't be modified whether SIP is on or off. I'm trying to determine what the OP has actually done, after being burned many times on this site because material information was withheld.
